# Extending classes with decorators in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'd like to extend a class with decorators but don't know how exactly. My current approach is as follows:

```
function Foo(value: string) {
    return function(target: Function) {
        let injected = Object.assign(target.prototype, { foo: value });
        return injected;
    }
}

@Foo("Hello world")
class Bar {
}

let instance = new Bar();
console.log(instance.foo); // Should say "Hello World"
```

But I can't instantiate my class anymore: "TypeError: Bar is not a constructor".

Where's my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to return a new object from the decorator. In this case target object will be modified, so just

```
function Foo(value: string) {
  return function(target: Function) {
    Object.assign(target.prototype, { foo: value });
  }
}
```

should work fine

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work. The `bar` object remains unchanged, trying to get `instance.foo` results in `Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'Bar'`.

Comment: @nehalist Do you have a flag `experimentalDecorators` in your tsconfig? It is working on my local and in playground https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/

Comment: @nehalist But if you're talking about warning from typescript it is just because TS compiler is unable to resolve this property. Just check generated JS in playground

Comment: It is not a good practice, but to suppress a warning on dynamic properties you could write `console.log((<any>instance).foo);`

Comment: Hmm, the only mentionable thing is that I'm on NodeJS, using ts-node. But even when compiling directly via CLI (`tsc Playground.ts --target ES5 --experimentalDecorators`) I still get `Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'Bar'`.

Comment: @nehalist you should cast your instance to any in console.log like `console.log((<any>instance).foo);`